# Why do elements of the Gel'fand spectrum map self-adjoint elements to points in the usual spectrum of the element?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, von-neumann-algebras, gelfand-representation

A. Döring says in the book "Deep Beauty
Understanding the Quantum World Through Mathematical Innovation", that, for the Gelfand spectrum defined as:

> **Definition:** A Gelfand spectrum $\Sigma_V$ consists of the positive linear functionals from a abelian subalgebra $V$ of a encompassing von Neumann algebra $\mathfrak{M}$, such that they have norm $1$ and are algebra homomorphisms from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

He then says that for any $\lambda \in \Sigma_V$, it can be shown that for any self-adjoint $A \in V_{sa}$, the following relation holds:
$$\lambda(A) \in \sigma(A)$$
where $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the usual spectrum of $A$.

How does one prove this? Is it a consequence of the Gelfand–Mazur theorem? In which case, is this then implied because $\lambda$ sends the self-adjoint $A$ to an arbitrary complex number and, by the Gelfand–Mazur theorem(?), the entirety of $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\sigma(A)$, making that arbitrary complex number be somewhere in $\sigma(A)$?

(Not sure if that is what the Gelfand–Mazur theorem implies, I kinda stumbled upon it when looking for the reason why $\lambda(A) \in \sigma(A)$, and from a surface reading of the statement of the theorem, he seems to be exactly what needs to be used to prove that type of relation.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a direct observation:
$$
\lambda(A-\lambda(A)1)=\lambda(A)-\lambda(A)=0,
$$
so $A-\lambda(A)\in\ker\lambda$. Because $\lambda$ is not zero, one easily check that $\lambda(1)$ has to be a projection; and the only nonzero projection in $\mathbb C$ is $1$. So $\lambda$ is unital. If $A-\lambda(A)1$ were invertible, then its image would have to be nonzero by the multiplicativity of $\lambda$. Hence $A-\lambda(A)1$ is not invertible, and $\lambda(A)\in\sigma(A)$.

With a bit more work one can show that on any unital abelian Banach algebra you have
$$
\sigma(A)=\{\lambda(A):\ \lambda:V\to\mathbb C\ \text{ nonzero homomorphism}\}. 
$$

Comment: One would still need to use the spectral decomposition of $A$ to be able to show that $\sigma(A)=\{\lambda(A) \, | \, \lambda \in \Sigma_V \}$, right?

Comment: @FelipeDilho: if you mean the Spectral Theorem, then no. This result holds in any unital Banach algebra. And you have to include zero if the Banach algebra is non-unital.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect this is unavoidably circular. See Martin's comment below.

If $\lambda(A)=0$, then you can show that $A$ is not invertible, so zero is in the spectrum.

Suppose $\lambda(A)$ is non-zero then consider $\mathrm{C}^*(A)$ the unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra generated by $A\in\mathfrak{M}$. This is isomorphic to $C(\sigma(A))$ where $A$ in $C(\sigma(A))$ is identified with the function $t\mapsto t$.

With $\lambda(A)$ non-zero, it restricted to $\mathrm{C}^*(A)$ is a character. And characters on $\mathrm{C}^*(A)$ are exactly evaluation functionals $\mathrm{ev}_x$ for some $x\in\sigma(A)$. So in this picture $\lambda(A)$ is nothing but $\mathrm{ev}_x(t\mapsto t)=x$.

Comment: The way I know how to prove this stuff, yes, this is circular. Because the proof that $C^*(A)$ is isomorphic to $C(\sigma(A))$ passes from first using the Gelfand transform to show that $C^*(A)\simeq C(\Sigma_{C^*(A)})$, and then using the result that $\sigma(A)=\{\tau(A):\ \tau\in\Sigma_{C^*(A)}\}$ to conclude that $\sigma(A)$ is homeomorphic to $\Sigma_{C^*(A)}$ and hence $C(\Sigma_{C^*(A)})$ is isomorphic to $C(\sigma(A))$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I suspected as much. Thanks for feedback on my answer.